# D3 - Visualize nodes in batches (avoid links intersection)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 library to visualize a directed graph based on the graph data. As I have huge data that is dynamic, it's difficult to arrange everything on a single page.

I am trying to segregate data by grouping them into batches and till now I couldn't come with better logic.

### **Current Behaviour**

Below is the snippet & code where it actually distributes the node at random location. Every time it will change.

[image]

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
}
    
graph.nodes.forEach(n => {
    n.fx = getRandomInt(0 , width); 
    n.fy = getRandomInt(0 , height);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .node {}
    
    .link {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: .6;
      stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    
    svg {
      border: 1px solid black
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.js"></script>
  
  <svg width="400" height="200"></svg>
  <script>
    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height"),
      node,
      link;

    svg.append('defs').append('marker')
      .attrs({
        'id': 'arrowhead',
        'viewBox': '-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX': 13,
        'refY': 0,
        'orient': 'auto',
        'markerWidth': 13,
        'markerHeight': 13,
        'xoverflow': 'visible'
      })
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
      .attr('fill', '#999')
      .style('stroke', 'none');

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      }).distance(100).strength(1))
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    var graph = {
      "nodes": [{
          "name": "Alpha",
          "label": "Person",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "Beta",
          "label": "Person",
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "Gamma",
          "label": "Database",
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Delta",
          "label": "Database",
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "name": "Echo",
          "label": "Person",
          "id": 5
        },
        {
          "name": "Foxtrot",
          "label": "Person",
          "id": 6
        },
        {
          "name": "Golf",
          "label": "Database",
          "id": 7
        },
        {
          "name": "Hotel",
          "label": "Database",
          "id": 8
        }
      ],
      "links": [{
          "source": 1,
          "target": 2,
          "type": "KNOWS",
          "since": 2010
        },
        {
          "source": 1,
          "target": 3,
          "type": "FOUNDED"
        },
        {
          "source": 2,
          "target": 3,
          "type": "WORKS_ON"
        },
        {
          "source": 3,
          "target": 4,
          "type": "IS_A"
        },
        {
          "source": 4,
          "target": 2,
          "type": "KNOWS",
          "since": 2010
        },
        {
          "source": 5,
          "target": 6,
          "type": "FOUNDED"
        },
        {
          "source": 3,
          "target": 4,
          "type": "WORKS_ON"
        },
        {
          "source": 1,
          "target": 4,
          "type": "IS_A"
        },
        {
          "source": 7,
          "target": 8,
          "type": "IS_A"
        }
      ]
    };

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
    }
    
    graph.nodes.forEach(n => {
        n.fx = getRandomInt(0 , width); 
        n.fy = getRandomInt(0 , height);
    });

    update(graph.links, graph.nodes);

    function update(links, nodes) {
      link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')

      link.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.type;
        });

      edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attrs({
          'class': 'edgepath',
          'fill-opacity': 0,
          'stroke-opacity': 0,
          'id': function(d, i) {
            return 'edgepath' + i
          }
        })
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

      edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attrs({
          'class': 'edgelabel',
          'id': function(d, i) {
            return 'edgelabel' + i
          },
          'font-size': 10,
          'fill': '#aaa'
        });

      edgelabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
          return '#edgepath' + i
        })
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr("startOffset", "50%")
        .text(function(d) {
          return ''
        });

      node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          //.on("end", dragended)
        );

      node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return colors(i);
        })

      node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", -3)
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        });

      simulation.nodes(nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

      simulation.force("link")
        .links(links);
    }

    function ticked() {

      link
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          checkBounds(d.source);
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          checkBounds(d.target);
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      node
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          checkBounds(d);
          return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
        });

      edgepaths.attr('d', function(d) {
        return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
      });

      edgelabels.attr('transform', function(d) {
        if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
          var bbox = this.getBBox();

          rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
          ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
          return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
        } else {
          return 'rotate(0)';
        }
      });
    }

    function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function checkBounds(d) {
      if (d.x < 0) d.x = 0;
      if (d.x > (width - 20)) d.x = width - 20;
      if (d.y < 0) d.y = 0;
      if (d.y > (height - 20)) d.y = height - 20;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Target

Below is what I am trying to achieve, not this specific display but link intersection should be avoided which will help to visualize the graph for huge data.
[image]